# Unexcepcted new line, beginner Python

Tags: python, printing

My goal is to make a program to use for creating flashcards and practicing language with. Right now I just want to read in a .txt file with a word and a translation, create a list from them and then print that list.

I am very much a beginner at programming.

My problem is that when it prints the list it looks like this:

```
att arbeta - travailler
att ga -  marcher
att tala
 -  parler
```

The last word couple is always one line to low. It should look like this:

```
att arbeta - travailler
att ga -  marcher
att tala -  parler
```

My code:

```
    wordList=[]

    def main ():
        buildList()
        for i in range(len(wordList)):
            print(wordList[i].returnPair())


    class wordCouple():
        def __init__(self, freWord, engWord):
            self.freWord = freWord
            self.engWord = engWord

        def returnPair(self):
            x = self.engWord + " - " + self.freWord
            return x

        def returnEng(self):
            return self.engWord

        def returnFre(self):
            return self.freWord

    def buildList():
        f=open("test.txt", "r")
        if f.mode == 'r':
            contents =f.read()
            data = contents.split("|")
            for i in range(len(data)): #I think the problem is here. Here I 
                wordSplit = data[i].split (",")
                wordList.append(wordCouple(wordSplit[0],wordSplit[1]))

        else:
            print("could not read text file")

    main()
```

This is how the test.txt file that I use in the program look like.

```
travailler, att arbeta| marcher, att ga| parler, att tala
```

Comment: Perhaps try `contents =f.read().strip()`. There is a newline character at the end of the line in the text file. You can strip it off.

Comment: I don't understand why it made a newline in the middle of a pair, but your solution definitely works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you read in the line of data, it has a newline character at the end; when you `.split()` that result, the last of those sections (here, `parler, att tala`) still has that newline at the end; and thus when you split it again, you still have the newline on `att tala` (and also the leading space).

Use the `.strip()` method of strings to remove leading and trailing whitespace - it produces a new string (strings cannot be modified in-place).

---

But while I have your attention:

```
for i in range(len(wordList)):
    print(wordList[i].returnPair())
```

Do not do this; if someone taught you to do this, do not listen to that person or source again; and if you came up with it yourself, then review your understanding and reasoning. In Python, `for` loops already give you the contents of your underlying iterable (here, `wordList`) directly; with code like this you are going out of your way to make things harder for yourself. What you want is instead:

```
for word in wordList:
    print(word.returnPair())
```

That is: you *directly ask for each `word` and use it* - instead of asking for how many words there are, and then figuring out all the numbers from 0 up to that count (non-inclusive), and then asking for those numbers individually, and finally using the numbers to grab the words. Simple :)

Comment: I could go on, but SO is not really a tutorial or learn-to-program site - it's a Q&A site. I just want to root this one particular habit out everywhere that I see it, because it's frankly mystifying to me how persistent it is.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out. Yes, your way looks way prettier and more effective. I am quite new to Python, so thank you.

One thing I don't understand is this: Why is there only an unwanted newline in the last pair? Why not in all pairs?